# Sending objects from GAE PersistenceManger to Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, serialization, persistence

I am writing an Android app that talks to a Google App Engine server. The server holds persistent data, which it stores and fetches using `PersistenceManager`. The way I have this set up now is as follows:

- A `@PersistenceCapable` class on the server called `StoredThingToRemember` has the information to remember, as well as some GAE object persistence jazz.
- When the Android client wants to fetch a `ThingToRemember`, it sends an HTTP request to the server, which fetches a `StoredThingToRemember` from a `PersistenceManager`, converts it to a `ThingToRemember implements Serializable`, serializes it as a `byte[]`, then sends it in an HTTP response.
- The client unserializes the `ThingToRemember` and uses it.

This works, but it seems wonky. Ideally, I would like to serialize and send the StoredThingToRemember itself. Unfortunately, that seems to require putting all the GAE object persistence classes in the Android app, which seems silly and wasteful.

What is the correct way to grab an object from GAE persistence and then use that object in an Android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using serialization formats for transmitting data is generally fairly risky - they're usually not designed with transmission across trust domains in mind. Further, by doing so you're locking yourself in - both your client and your server will always have to be written in Java. Any further clients will either have to be written in Java, or will require a whole new interface.

Instead, you should serialize to a language-independent format, such as XML or JSON.

Comment: Which classes would you use for this purpose, both on the serializing and deserializing end?

Comment: @Andrew Classes are secondary. You should be looking into serialization frameworks - pick a format that suits (XML is typical for Java and there are probably good built-in libraries for it; JSON is a good option that's easy to read and write in general), then follow its standard approach for serializing data.

Comment: I agree that using Java's built-in serialization format is probably not a good idea here.  However, I'd strongly recommend against XML (bad data model).  JSON's not bad, but something like Google Protocol Buffers or Apache Thrift would be better (there are implementations for many languages; they handle some of the structural validation for you; they both have a text format and an equivalent binary format that has better performance).  Other tools: https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/ToolBehavior

Comment: @Kannan I should've mentioned protocol buffers. :) Using them would pretty much rule out a web-based client, thougg.

Comment: @Nick: I'm not sure how mature or efficient they are, but there are at least two Protocol Buffer implementations for Javascript: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns

Comment: @Nick: Why not?  Too slow?  Bloats the JS download?  Another option is to have the server offer multiple formats.  The Protostuff library makes it easy to use a single set of Protobuf classes internally but parse/render to multiple formats, including JSON: http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/wiki/JsonSerialization

Comment: @Kannan JS really isn't built for parsing or generating binary data - it doesn't even have a 'byte' datatype. Any solution is going to involve horrible hacks with strings. You're right about libraries like protostuff, though - protorpc is another such.